# issue working with 3d arrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

### `First Question`:

regarding my code here :

```
for z = [1 2 4 8 12 16 24 32 64 96 128]    
    for a=1:24
        a;
        for d=1:5
            d;
           [result]=evolRand(128,1,10,1,bench);
           bb= 5*(a-1)+d;
           temp=eval(['minExe_useModel_' num2str(z)]);
           %z=num2str(zz)
           exploreff(a,d,z) =mean(mean(result(a,d).randMin(:,2:end)))/temp(bb);
        end
    end
end
```

why at the end I am getting :

```
>>size(exploreff)

ans =

    24     5   128
```

while I had assigned `z= [1 2 4 8 12 16 24 32 64 96 128]` which was `11` ??

### `Second Question`:

How am I gonna be able to define a array of structure out of these z so that I can call them like `exploreff(a,b).z` ? cuz defining them like this in the script caused the

```
Structure assignment to non-structure object.

Error in explorationEffort_Speedup (line 15)
           exploreff(aa,dd).z=mean(mean(result(aa,dd).randMin(:,2:end)))/temp(bb);`
```

error.

Comment: For the first question, make sure that you do `clear exploreff` before the loop and check the dimension of `mean(mean(result(a,d).randMin(:,2:end)))/temp(bb)`.

Comment: It is only 1. As it is the 2d mean

Comment: Nvm the reason that it has 128 in its last dimension is that you have 128 in the array `z = [1 2 4 8 12 16 24 32 64 96 128]`.

Comment: Seems so, to avoid this what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

```
exploreff(a,d,z)
```

uses `a`, `d` and `z` as *indices*, therefore you're assigning 11 values to the 1st, 2nd, 4th, ... 96th and 128th indices along the 3rd dimension. Matlab automatically expands (and zero-fills) the array when you assign to an index outside its current dimensions, hence why the 3rd dimension ends up at 128 elements long.

Secondly, if `exploreff` is preallocated as a numeric array you can't just start addressing it as a structure. If you preallocate it as a struct array (using `struct`) first, then dynamically expanding it and adding fields  in that way should be ok (I only have Octave to test, and that lets me do e.g. `a(2,3).z = 5` straight off but I seem to recall Matlab wanting either the index or the field to exist first - that *was* 2007a though...).

Comment: i see but what should i do to avoid this auto-assignment of zero?

Comment: and I tried `exploreeff = repmat(struct ('num2str(z(1))',[], 'num2str(z(2))',[], 'num2str(z(3))',[], 'num2str(z(4))',[], 'num2str(z(5))',[], 'num2str(z(6))',[], 'num2str(z(7))',[], 'num2str(z(8))',[], 'num2str(z(9))',[], 'num2str(z(10))',[], 'num2str(z(11))',[])); but it doesn't work`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do...

```
z = [1 2 4 8 12 16 24 32 64 96 128];

for i = 1:length(z)
    for a=1:24
        a;
        for d=1:5
            d;
           [result]=evolRand(128,1,10,1,bench);
           bb= 5*(a-1)+d;
           temp=eval(['minExe_useModel_' num2str(z(i))]);
           %z=num2str(zz)
           exploreff(a,d,z(i)) =mean(mean(result(a,d).randMin(:,2:end)))/temp(bb);
        end
    end
end

exploreff(a,d,z==8)
```

Note that `z` in the loop is replaced by `z(i)`. Instead of directly specifying the value you want, you need to specify the index of the element. In the last line, `z==8` specify the index of the element in vector `z` that has `8` value.

Comment: tnx for the answer, but not quit sure why the last line is outside the loop? cuz still i am having these auto-assigned zero in between the z numbers

Comment: Instead of calling `exploreff(a,b).z` you call something like `exploreff(a,d,z==c)` where c is some number in the vector z. If c is not in z you should get an empty matrix.

Comment: yes, only in this case it give am empty matrix, cuz in later steps I wanna make some other stat functions over these and I don't want these 0 affect my results

Comment: then you need to define what value you want to get out when you put some other values for z. do you want to interpolate the value over the domain of z or what?

Comment: No. Those were like discrete values as input that I used to calculate exploreff. Anyhow, i take some time to process all values z=1:128 in order to have continuous input and get rid of the  issue!